# In Spring what is the exact difference between scope="singleton" and singleton="true"

Tags: spring

In one interview i have faced this question. In spring configuration file, if we give scope="singleton" what happens and singleton="true" what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in Spring 1.x there were only two scopes, *prototype* and *singleton*, so there was only a `singleton=true` or a `singleton=false`. Quoting the DTD:

> Bean instances can be "singletons" (shared instances) or "prototypes"
>       (independent instances). Further scopes are supposed to be built on top
>       of the core BeanFactory infrastructure and are therefore not part of it.

([Source](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/springbeansdtd.html))

However, this did not allow them to introduce other scopes, so they changed the DTD in Spring 2, to `scope="singleton"` and `scope="prototype"`. This allowed them to introduce other scopes as well, such as `scope="session"` and `scope="request"`. You can verify this in the [DTD of Spring 2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/springbeansdtd.html) and onwards.

---

So, to answer your question, normally they should be the same, but in different versions of Spring.

Comment: Hight time for that interviewer to throw away and forget the baggage that he carry along from ancient world. LOL